# Magento 1.6.2 Remove Paypal order statuses

Tags: magento, paypal

I'm running Magento 1.6.2 and want to remove Paypal order statuses. They are not being used at all and they pollute my order status list. Disabling Paypal does not work.

Magento 1.6.2 does have the nice ability to manage order statuses in the admin, but the Paypal statuses are non-removable.

Is there any way to hard remove them from the database or maybe just hide them somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you that you don't want to remove them, `Mage_Paypal_Model_Info` uses them to check if the payment is in review, fraud, processed or completed.  I would recommend that you just deal with them.  They exist as const for a purpose, even though you may not actually use them but they are used behind the scenes.  They do more good than they really do harm.

```
   /**
     * Check whether the payment is in review state
     *
     * @param Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPaymentReviewRequired(Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment)
    {
        $paymentStatus = $payment->getAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_STATUS_GLOBAL);
        if (self::PAYMENTSTATUS_PENDING === $paymentStatus) {
            $pendingReason = $payment->getAdditionalInformation(self::PENDING_REASON_GLOBAL);
            return !in_array($pendingReason, array('authorization', 'order'));
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether fraud order review detected and can be reviewed
     *
     * @param Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isFraudReviewAllowed(Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment)
    {
        return self::isPaymentReviewRequired($payment)
            && 1 == $payment->getAdditionalInformation(self::IS_FRAUD_GLOBAL);
    }

    /**
     * Check whether the payment is completed
     *
     * @param Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPaymentCompleted(Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment)
    {
        $paymentStatus = $payment->getAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_STATUS_GLOBAL);
        return self::PAYMENTSTATUS_COMPLETED === $paymentStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether the payment was processed successfully
     *
     * @param Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPaymentSuccessful(Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment)
    {
        $paymentStatus = $payment->getAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_STATUS_GLOBAL);
        if (in_array($paymentStatus, array(
            self::PAYMENTSTATUS_COMPLETED, self::PAYMENTSTATUS_INPROGRESS, self::PAYMENTSTATUS_REFUNDED,
            self::PAYMENTSTATUS_REFUNDEDPART, self::PAYMENTSTATUS_UNREVERSED, self::PAYMENTSTATUS_PROCESSED,
        ))) {
            return true;
        }
        $pendingReason = $payment->getAdditionalInformation(self::PENDING_REASON_GLOBAL);
        return self::PAYMENTSTATUS_PENDING === $paymentStatus
            && in_array($pendingReason, array('authorization', 'order'));
    }

    /**
     * Check whether the payment was processed unsuccessfully or failed
     *
     * @param Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isPaymentFailed(Mage_Payment_Model_Info $payment)
    {
        $paymentStatus = $payment->getAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_STATUS_GLOBAL);
        return in_array($paymentStatus, array(
            self::PAYMENTSTATUS_DENIED, self::PAYMENTSTATUS_EXPIRED, self::PAYMENTSTATUS_FAILED,
            self::PAYMENTSTATUS_REVERSED, self::PAYMENTSTATUS_VOIDED,
        ));
    }
```

If you look in `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml` you can find this,

```
<sales>
    <order>
        <statuses>
            <pending_paypal translate="label">
                <label>Pending PayPal</label>
            </pending_paypal>
        </statuses>
    </order>
</sales>
```

but look at app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml

```
        <!-- /**
              * @depraceted after 1.4.2, statuses are saved into sales_order_status table
              */
        -->
```

You should look in the sales_order_status table in the database if you are using version after 1.4.2, the only reason they exist in the config.xml to to ensure backwards compatibility.

This is the section that adds the Pending PayPal status, you could comment/delete and have it remove it, but I would recommend that you find out where this status is used before you remove it so that you don't have any unseen conflicts, you can use `grep -r 'sales_order_status' *` in app/code and lib/ to find anything that may use this table and when it might use `Pending PayPal`.